# How do I block a query thread when another thread is updating the database?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a server that makes a child thread for every user that connects to the server.The child server class has the run method and other methods.

One method searches a mysql database with select.

Another method updates the databases.

How can I block the method that searches the database when another thread uses the method that updates the database ?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ ?

Comment: it seems the client will be unhappy waiting  the method that searches the database when another thread uses the method that updates the database

Comment: Are you asking this because the query is pulling partially update results or for some other reason?

Answer (score 7):

The *proper* way to handle your requirement is to do all database operations within a *transaction*. This will avoid any need of the mutual exclusion of database code and will also guarantee isolation between your Java process and any other database client doing its own operations.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is database transaction and proper [isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)  level.

Below are some isolation levels in MySql:

> Read uncommitted
>
> Read committed
>
> Repeatable reads
>
> Serializable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have a good design doing this, but if you want mutex on a method, declare the method as synchronized like

```
public synchronized void putInDbase(String value) {
  //only one thread will execute here at a time
}
```

But if you have two seperate methods within the same class, you want to synchronize the actual code dealing with the database, you can make synchronized blocks

```
public class myDbase {
     public void search() {

    synchronized(this) {
     //database code
    }

}

public void update() {

   synchronized(this) {
      //database code
   }

}

}
```

Comment: That only works if the instance of the class containing that method is shared, which is unclear from the question.

Comment: Very true statement. @Emil see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html